# How to convert from a paid app to in app purchase? iOS and Android + Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I have an app that I have marketing and sold successfully for the first year of it's existence as a paid app for both iOS and Android.  The app is developed in Flutter.

I would like to move to a freemium model using in app purchases.  For Android/Google Play, I am planning to just make a 2nd Android app that has the in app purchase functionality.  I will continue to maintain the paid app as well.

I'm at a loss as to what to do for iOS.  I've read that I should be able to mine the original purchase date, but I'm not sure how to get this information.  I'm familiar with in_app_purchase but I don't believe this resolves this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I need to do the same thing, but I'm unsure what is the best way.

Comment: Yes, RevenueCat is the answer!  It exposes the original installed version.  Be aware that this value is not actually the app version, it is the build version.

Comment: For Android I have kept both the paid version and the freemium version alive, and that works really well.  I have been making more money with both of them going than I did with just one.  For Apple, you have no choice but to use the one single app.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Apple receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) there is a field, `original_application_version`.

You can check the value of this field when a user restores purchases to see if they had originally installed the app from a paid version and grant them "premium" access.

I'm not super familiar with the in_app_purchase plugin specifically and if they expose this field or not.

Comment: I have read about this, but I have not found any flutter libraries that expose this value.  The search continues...!

Comment: This one [has it](https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter/blob/af95d904c0a5e093e9058d07f6fbba74af4cbdb8/lib/purchaser_info_wrapper.dart#L38): https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter